# What is the correct regular expression to get JUST the ID from HTML?

Tags: regex

I am using JMeter and trying to use the Regular Expression Extraction step, and I need to get just an ID from html.

The line in question is

`<a href="EditBudget.psp?jobTokenID=978025" TABINDEX="24" >Edit budget for project Perf09035710810: .</a>`

I am unable to figure out the correct regular expression for just getting the ID extracted (just the 978025), and need help making this dynamic.

The closest I've gotten so far is

```
(EditBudget)+(.+?).\"
```

but that returns: EditBudget.psp?jobTokenID=978025"

Comment: If you want to use a regex, it should look like `EditBudget[.]psp[?]jobTokenID=([0-9]+)` and use `$1$` template.

Comment: If one of the answers helped, please accept it. It's not good form to leave questions marked as unanswered when you've gotten several that seem to answer your question -- and if they don't, edit your question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, group 1 match is the id

```
/jobTokenID=(.[^"]*)"/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it must be said that using a regex is probably a bad idea, because HTML is not a regular language.

Secondly, if your ID is *always* in the `href`, and it is *always* after that `EditBudget.psp?`, and it's *always* numeric, then you can just use this:

```
EditBudget\.psp\?jobTokenID=(\d+)
```

Then you just need to get group 1.

If you want to have the regex match only the ID, you'll need an engine which supports backreferences, and you can use:

```
(?<=EditBudget\.psp\?jobTokenID=)\d+
```

Then the entirety of what the regex matches is your ID.

If there's no other instances of `jobTokenID=` except immediately preceeding an ID you want to get, you can just do

```
(?<!jobTokenID=)\d+
```

NB: If your ID isn't always numeric, replace `\d` with the [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) representing all of the allowable characters. Cross-reference that with the engine for your language to make sure that it's supported before using it.